# Google Analytics for Firebase in BigQuery without exported ga data

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, google-bigquery

Currently, we have an app that uses Firebase, with Google Analytics enabled, and linked to BigQuery. The firebase account is on the `Spark` program.

In BigQuery, I can see the event-based schema, with fields around events and users and a few additional things like geo.

I am not sure what I need to do to get the session-related data in BigQuery, with things like `session.visitId` (found it referenced as part of `ga_analytics_*` table that I am missing). Does this require enabling the `Blaze plan` and export the google analytics data to BigQuery? Is this the reason why I am not seeing the session related fields in BigQuery?

If that is the case, what is the event-driven data model that I am currently seeing called in the Firebase context?

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase Export to BigQuery](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en&ref_topic=7029512) has a specific schema. In the docs the tables are in the form `events_YYYYMMDD` (this could be the event-driven data you asked for) and session.visitId is not listed as a field.

The field visitId seems to belong to [Google Analytics BigQuery Export](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en&ref_topic=3416089) whose table is in the form `ga_sessions_YYYYMMDD`. Firebase docs specify that [if your Firebase project is on the free Spark plan, you can link ... Google Analytics ... to the BigQuery sandbox](https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/bigquery-export#pricing), so, it should be feasible to access the ga tables in the sandbox. It is possible that an additional step is missing to get ga tables exported to BigQuery.